# A accessToken is not valid for connecting to Azure DevOps deployment group from Windows server

Tags: windows, powershell, azure-devops

In Azure Devops Server, I have created a group in  `Deployment Groups`. A registration script was created for run in the target server. This is the generated script.

> $ErrorActionPreference="Stop";If(-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent() ).IsInRole( [Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] “Administrator”)){ throw "Run command in an administrator PowerShell prompt"};If($PSVersionTable.PSVersion -lt (New-Object System.Version("3.0"))){ throw "The minimum version of Windows PowerShell that is required by the script (3.0) does not match the currently running version of Windows PowerShell." };If(-NOT (Test-Path $env:SystemDrive'azagent')){mkdir $env:SystemDrive'azagent'}; cd $env:SystemDrive'azagent'; for($i=1; $i -lt 100; $i++){$destFolder="A"+$i.ToString();if(-NOT (Test-Path ($destFolder))){mkdir $destFolder;cd $destFolder;break;}}; $agentZip="$PWD\agent.zip";$DefaultProxy=[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy;$securityProtocol=@();$securityProtocol+=[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol;$securityProtocol+=[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol=$securityProtocol;$WebClient=New-Object Net.WebClient; $Uri='https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2066756';if($DefaultProxy -and (-not $DefaultProxy.IsBypassed($Uri))){$WebClient.Proxy= New-Object Net.WebProxy($DefaultProxy.GetProxy($Uri).OriginalString, $True);}; $WebClient.DownloadFile($Uri, $agentZip);Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem;[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory( $agentZip, "$PWD");.\config.cmd --deploymentgroup --deploymentgroupname "DG-Test" --agent $env:COMPUTERNAME --runasservice --work '_work' --url 'https://devops.MyCompany.com/tfs/' --collectionname 'Col-FRN-Main' --projectname 'T-MyCompany'; Remove-Item $agentZip;

I run the script then PowerShell asks me to `Enter authentication type (press enter for PAT)`, so I enter an accessToken that is generated in `Personal Access Token` but PowerShell returns `Enter authentication type (press enter for PAT)`.
I could use the accessToken for connecting Team explorer in Visual studio to my DevOps server and connecting agent pool to my DevOps server, but I have trouble connecting deployment agnet.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When PowerShell asks you to Enter authentication type (press enter for PAT), you are supposed to press enter on your keyboard. Then it will prompt you to enter your Personal Access Token. Follow the prompts and you should be able to connect successfully.